# Error trying to show paypal button in client side integration

Tags: javascript, flask, paypal

I'm trying to integrate paypal on an ecommerce website making the client side integration described in:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#2-add-the-paypal-javascript-sdk-to-your-web-page

One of the first steps consists in adding the paypal button on the page:

1. I created a test flask html template called payPalTest.html that extends the base template called base.html and I created a dedicated route /payPalTest
2. in base.html I added:
   `<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb"></script>`
3. in payPalTest.html I added:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block payPalTest %}
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    <script>
    paypal.Buttons().render('#paypal-button-container');
    // This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
    </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

and this is the full content of /payPalTest when you reach the url:

```html
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>imemoi: exclusive luxury bags</title>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import Font awesome icons -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import Google Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arimo&amp;family=Playfair+Display+Lato&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import main.css and materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/prompt.js"></script></head>

<body>

    <!-- header-menu -->
    <div class="row no-margin-bottom">
        <div class="header-menu valign-wrapper center-align">
            <div class="col s12 m12 l3">
                <!--main logo-->
                <a href="/">
                    <img src="/static/images/logo_black.png" width="250" height="133">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="bags" class="col s12 m4 l3 clickable">BAGS</div>
            <div id="accessories" class="col s12 m4 l3 clickable">ACCESSORIES</div>
            <div id="living" class="col s12 m4 l3 clickable">LIVING</div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<script>
  paypal.Buttons().render('#paypal-button-container');
  // This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
</script>

    <!-- footer -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="footer valign-wrapper center-align">
            <div id="imemoi" class="col offset-s2 s8 offset-s2 m2 l2 clickable">IMEMOI</div>
            <div id="press" class="col offset-s2 s8 offset-s2 m2 l2 clickable">PRESS</div>
            <div class="col offset-s2 s8 offset-s2 m4 l4 social-icons">
                <ul>
                    <li id="fb-icon"><i class="clickable fa fa-facebook"></i></li>
                    <li id="is-icon"><i class="clickable fa fa-instagram"></i></li>
                    <li id="pi-icon"><i class="clickable fa fa-pinterest"></i></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="making-of" class="col offset-s2 s8 offset-s2 m4 l2 clickable">MAKING OF &amp; ENGAGEMENT</div>
            <div id="legal" class="col offset-s2 s8 offset-s2 offset-m2 m8 offset-m2 l2 clickable">LEGAL</div>
            <div id="contact-us" class="col offset-s2 s8 offset-s2 offset-m2 m8 offset-m2 offset-l2 l8 offset-l2 clickable contacts">CONTACT US</div>
            <div id="subscribe" class="col offset-s2 s8 offset-s2 offset-m2 m8 offset-m2 offset-l2 l8 offset-l2 clickable contacts">SUBCRIBE AND GET THE 15% OFF !!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVooZr5SuB_fro4zOf7rII7A2Q2MYeCKr_vj532fbft449Mj5RTuGm_f7-6hT81ZbRhaoBx4ulX_TIVe"></script>


</body></html>
```

When I run the application and I reach the route http://127.0.0.1:5000/payPalTest the payPal button is not displayed and on the console I get:

Uncaught ReferenceError: paypal is not defined
at payPalTest:49

Note: Web site is made using Python Flask.

Comment: Post the HTML content of /payPalTest as served to/saved from your web browser

Comment: I added the HTML content shown in the browser when you reach /payPalTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PayPal JS script

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=..."></script>
```

Is loading after you try to render the buttons, so the `paypal` object doesn't exist when the button tries to render.

You need to ensure the script loads before you try to render the buttons, i.e. it needs to appear first on the page. One way to do this is to load the resource from `<head>`